# Ansible variable selectattr then map then equality

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this API result:

```
ok: [myserver] => {
    "result": {
        # ...
        "json": [
            {
                "active": true,
                "created": "2023-07-22T15:25:34+04:00",
                "description": "",
                "id": 1,
                "language": "en-US",
                "username": "mike",
                "visibility": "private",
                # ...
            },
            {
                # ...
            },
            # ...
        ],
        # ...
    }
}
```

I want to check the value of `visibility` for the element that has `username` of `mike`.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg="{{result.json | selectattr('username', 'equalto', 'mike') | map(attribute='visibility') == 'private'}}"
```

Which gives:

```bash
TASK [myplaybook : debug] ****************************************************
ok: [myserver] => {
    "msg": false
}
```

I expected `true`. So obviously my syntax is incorrect - how do I fix it?

Comment: Without any testing environnement or so: `map(attribute='some')` will always return you a list, so it can, at best be `== ['private']`.

Comment: This said if your usernames are uniques, you'd be better getting the first element of the list given by `selectattr`: `(result.json | selectattr('username', 'equalto', 'mike')).0.visibility == 'private'`

Comment: Or use `json_query`: `result | json_query('result[?name == \`mike\` && visibility == \` private\`]') | length > 0`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yes, I just tested `map(attribute='visibility') | type_debug == 'list'`. So your `== ['private']` solution is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of usernames and their visibility. For example, given the below data for testing

```yaml
  result:
    json:
      - {username: mike, visibility: private}
      - {username: alice, visibility: public}
      - {username: bob, visibility: top secret}
```

Declare the dictionary

```yaml
  username_visibility: "{{ result.json|
                           items2dict(key_name='username',
                                      value_name='visibility') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  username_visibility:
    alice: public
    bob: top secret
    mike: private
```

Now, the testing is trivial

```yaml
  username_visibility.mike == 'private'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result:
      json:
        - {username: mike, visibility: private}
        - {username: alice, visibility: public}
        - {username: bob, visibility: top secret}

    username_visibility: "{{ result.json|
                             items2dict(key_name='username',
                                        value_name='visibility') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: username_visibility

    - assert:
        that: username_visibility.mike == 'private'
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  username_visibility:
    alice: public
    bob: top secret
    mike: private

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```